# Mui v5 no overlaod matches when styling a material ui component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

As described in the picture, I am just trying to add more style to a Material UI Component (TextField), however no matter what I tried I keep getting this error. Never had a problem when I used `styled-components` though.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

material-ui (MUI) has already given a way to customize the UI as the develop needs. There are a few steps you can follow to customize the UI/ add new styles to MUI components.

1. One-off customization

   ```
           <Slider
          defaultValue={30}
          sx={{
            width: 300,
            color: 'success.main',
          }}
        />
   ```
2. Overriding nested component styles.

   ```
    <Slider
      defaultValue={30}
      sx={{
    width: 300,
    color: 'success.main',
    '& .MuiSlider-thumb': {
      borderRadius: '1px',
    },
     }}
    />
   ```
3. Overriding styles with class names

   `<MenuItem selected className="MenuItem">`

You can read more about this on MUI official documents: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-styles-with-class-names